# Do IIS 7 Limitations Affect What Self-Contained ASP.NET Core Apps Can Also Do?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, websocket, windows-7

I have an ASP.NET Core self-contained web app that was deployed on a Windows 7 IIS instance that almost works except for one key (and very important) feature and that is WebSockets.

I am aware that IIS 7 itself does not support WebSockets (as per MS documentation) but that ASP.NET Core apps can. I was under the impression that since my app is self-contained, I would be able to run an app that used WebSockets, but from testing so far, while I can access "http://localhost/app_name" and see the graphical interface just fine, when I attempt to connect via a JavaScript WebSocket to the same URL (ws://localhost/app_name), I get a connection error and unfortunately, JavaScript WebSockets errors don't give much detail other than the generic 1006 error code.

So basically, are self-contained ASP.NET Core apps that are published through IIS also limited by what IIS itself can do?

Comment: If it runs on IIS then it’s running on IIS and anything IIS supports or not is taken into account. Being self-contained or not doesn’t affect this in any way

Comment: IIS 7 is now end of life, so wasting your time on that platform is just a waste of time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0 It says clearly that you can only run ASP.NET Core alone (self hosting) if you want WebSockets on legacy Windows versions. Any tie to IIS requires you to be on IIS 8 and above.

Comment: That is what I suspected. The packaged app was given to one of my users who is still running Windows 7 due to some legacy software that he has to have access to until that legacy software can be updated or replaced.